# 206: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: function, undefined, typeerror

hey i am trying to learn how to use p5. but i have got a problem that i cant fix.
i am trying to do same as the coding train does in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXuxYMGe4KI&index=22&list=WL&t=619s

so far i have made this. and i keep getting this message 206: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. and please keep in mind that i haven't called mine blob and blobs, mine is called player and players, because it does no difference. thank you.

Here's my code so far:

```
var Player;

var players = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas (600, 600);
  player = new Player(width/2, height/2, 64);
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var x = random(-width, width*2);
    var y = random(-height, height*2);
    players[i] = new Player(x, y, 16);
  }
} 
function draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width/2-player.pos.x, height/2-player.pos.y);

  for (var i = players.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    players[i].show();
    if (player.eats(players[i])) {
      players.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }


player.show();
player.update();

}
function Player(x, y, r) {
  this.pos = createVector(x, y);
  this.r = r;
  this.update = function() {
    var vel = createVector(mouseX-width/2, mouseY-height/2);
    vel.setMag(3);
    this.pos.add(vel);
  }

  this.eats = function(other) {
    var d = p5.Vector.dist(this.pos, other.pos);
    if (d < this.r + other.r) {
      var sum = PI * this.r * this.r * PI * other.r * other.r;
      this.r = sqrt(sum / PI);
      //this.r += other.r*0.2;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }
  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r*2, this.r*2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the relevant code here. It's entirely possible to paste it here. Paste the relevant parts, then highlight it and press ctrl+k.

Comment: Of all the places to post code, why google docs?